# Are the single-engine Piper Malibus required to have a black box?

Tags: flight-data-recorder

Is the single engine Piper Malibu required to have a black box?

Comment: Required by who, the operator, the FAA, the EASA?

Comment: Jimy, I am not sure.  I have been following the story of Argentine soccer player Emiliano Alva who was traveling in a Piper Malibu on Monday, and the plane has not been located.  The FDR and CVR have never been mentioned, so I just was curious as to why.  Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it probably does not require a "black box".

What you refer to as a "black box" is actually 2 things (and [Orange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/why-are-fdrs-called-black-boxes-when-they-are-actually-orange)!) a Flight Data Recorder and a Cockpit Voice Recorder. The rules on when they are required is broadly similar, however the data required to be captured by the FDR varies.

For the [CVR](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Cockpit_Voice_Recorder_(CVR)):

> Fixed-wing aeroplanes with a maximum take-off mass of more than 5 700 kg and for which the certificate of airworthiness is first issued after 1 January 2003 shall be equipped with a CVR with a recording duration of two hours

For the [FDR](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Flight_Data_Recorder_(FDR)):

> [...] depending on the maximum certificated take-off mass and the date of first issue of the individual certificate of airworthiness. For example, provision 6.3.6 of Annex 6, Vol. I states that, all aeroplanes of a maximum certificated take-off mass of over 5,700 kg for which the individual certificate of airworthiness is first issued after 1 January 2005 shall be equipped with a Type IA FDR

The [Piper PA-46](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_PA-46) (aka Piper Malibu) has a MTOW ranging from 4,340lb(1,969kg) to 6,000lb(2,721kg).

Speculation about the recent incident, and the specific model intentionally left out!

Comment: Jamiec, Thank you for your comment.

Comment: 5800kg? How did that number become so golden? I'm just curious as these things sometimes have an interesting backstory.

Comment: @Dannie 5700kg is (more or less) 12,500lbs, which is the FAA's regulatory definition of a "large aircraft" and also means that a type rating is required. See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/56517/62).