# What is the origin/history/background for performance categories A,B,C?

Tags: aircraft-performance, transport-category

What is the thought process behind performance categories A,B and C?

I know they were done based on MTOW 5700 kg, 9 pax and engine drive.

I understand the table of classification, but I would like to know the thought process behind that. No ATPL book has explained it in a good way.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: I believe that some apparently random breakpoints were created due to specs and capability of aircraft in common use at the time.

Comment: I would like to know the background and why it is the way it is. Thanks.

Comment: Understood, if I knew more details I would answer.  Sorry!  I’ve read somewhere, (maybe here) that the weight or passenger count of the popular DC3 formed the basis of a category break decision.  Have you tried searching here or elsewhere?  Maybe my comment will prove a clue to a keyword search that gets you to an answer…

Comment: See this [question and answers](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/56517/19), perhaps it answers yours

Comment: Please include the jurisdiction you are asking about. ABCD[E] performance categories are used entirely different in the USA and designate the design speed ranges for instrument approach minima, totally independent of aircraft mass.

Comment: @MaxPower...jurisdictions is JAR. But it's not about the speed. It's the performance categories.